# re.groups() return nothing

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regex area ! I am trying to understand groups functionality.
Here is my string:

```
 ** server can\'t find mywebdomain.com: NXDOMAIN
```

Here is my regex:

```
match = re.match('[*]{2}\s+server.*NXDOMAIN')
```

Here is the value of the match I see in debugger:

```
match="** server can't find testweb.com: NXDOMA>
```

So I am trying to see groups on this regex.

```
match.groups()
```

but it returns nothing for me while I would expect to get a tuple.
so I do not really understand why it returns nothing?

Comment: Is `NXDOMA>` a typo? You're regex won't match that with the expression has `NXDOMAIN`

Comment: `match = re.match('[*]{2}\s+server.*NXDOMAIN')` - where is a second argument?

Comment: Because it doesn't match anything

Comment: @m_callens you are right! strange to me! I just copied it from debbuger

Comment: @quikst3r but I get result for match! can u describe a bit?

Comment: @user2091416 show us this result

Comment: there is NO groups on this regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `.groups()` returns the results of a matched regular expression's capturing groups, denoted in the expression by `(<expression>)`.

In you expression `[*]{2}\s+server.*NXDOMAIN`, there are no sub-expressions enclosed in `()` which would create a capturing group. Therefore, regardless of if you test positive for a match on your string, `.groups()` will always be empty because you haven't defined any capturing groups in your RegEx.

The other issue is that your your call to `re.match()`, you're specifying the expression you want to test with, but you aren't passing the string you want to test against... The format of the call is `re.match(<expression>, <string>)`

---

If you really want to use capturing groups you can surround your expression in `()`, and do...

```
match = re.match(r'([*]{2}\s+server.*NXDOMAIN)', '** server can\'t find mywebdomain.com: NXDOMAIN')
print(match.groups())
# ("** server can't find mywebdomain.com: NXDOMAIN",)
```

This results a `tuple` of your capturing group results.

The other option is to keep your expression as is, and instead use the `re.findall` function to get your match...

```
result = re.findall(r'[*]{2}\s+server.*NXDOMAIN', '** server can\'t find mywebdomain.com: NXDOMAIN')
print(result)
# ["** server can't find mywebdomain.com: NXDOMAIN"]
```

...and it returns an array with all matches found in your test string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a capturing group () in your regex in oder to capture matches in the groups() function. Also, the string to match should be passed as the second argument to the match() function. The following code should work.

```
import re
m = re.match("([*]{2}\s+server.*NXDOMAIN)",
  "** server can\'t find mywebdomain.com: NXDOMAIN")
if m:
  print(m.groups())
```